# Node.js and MongoDB Atlas Mongoose Connection Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect a MongoDB atlas instance to a nodejs/express server :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dbURI =
 "mongodb+srv://(url copied from atlas connect)";

const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  dbName: "data"
};

mongoose.connect(dbURI, options).then(
 () => {
   console.log("Database connection established!");
 },
 err => {
   console.log("Error connecting Database instance due to: ", err);
 }
);
```

But I keep get the following error:

> MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster ... 27017 closes at TLSSocket. ...

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: @jman93 version 5.3.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved -- Check IP whitelist!

Comment: so glad you answered your question. solved my issue.

Comment: It works for dynamics IP too? My IP change every 12 hours